# Separate the worksheet present in a single Excl Workbook using logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

My requirement is like in a excel file there are three different sheets are there I need to split those sheets to individual file and save to blob storage is this possible or not by using azure logic apps?

If possible, can anyone explain the workflow.

I tried with "Get Worksheets " connector from azure logic apps there I select the file Tried to getting all the worksheets.

[image]

After I tried to add those file into blob storage but that simply save the name.  Tried to create the blob.

[image]

And the output its not storing the xlxs file.

[image]

Blob Storage

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyqIv.png)

Comment: Currently, it is not feasible in logic app to read the content of a excel file. In order to store the actual content of your worksheet you need to write function code inside logic app workflow. In your way it will simply store the logic app output inside the blob while creating the blob

Answer (score 0):

> My requirement is like in a excel file there are three different sheets are there I need to split those sheets to individual file and save to blob storage is this possible or not by using azure logic apps?

Unfortunately, there is no action neither in **Excel Online(Business)** nor in **Excel online(OneDrive)** connector which can fetch the excel worksheet content. You can only get the rows from table not the whole excel content.

*Following actions are available in logic app-*

[image]

Even I have created the same workflow alike you but its only uploading the worksheets as an individual file unto blob storage with having logic app output as a blob content but not the actual excel sheet content, as we are unable to fetch it using the existing actions in the connector.

Tried to add all the available properties in blob content field but only logic app output is getting saved.

**Workflow:**

[image]

**Storage Account:**

I have the following data in the excel file

[image]

As there is no action available in logic app to fetch the actual excel content, so adding the logic app output as blob content.

[image]

I would suggest you to raise a feature request in GitHub with all the required information.